# Trigonometric system : calculating $\cos \frac{\pi}{5} $ & $\cos \frac{3\pi}{5}$

Tags: trigonometry

1) Solve in $\mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{cases}
 x+y & = \frac{1}{2}  \\
-xy & = -\frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}         (This already done I'm definitely not that stupid )

2) Knowing that :

\begin{cases}
\cos \frac{\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{3\pi}{5} & = \frac{1}{2}  \\
\cos \frac{\pi}{5} \cdot \cos \frac{3\pi}{5} & = -\frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}

Calculate $$\cos \frac{\pi}{5} $$ and $$\cos \frac{3\pi}{5}$$

3) Show that

$$ 1 + 2\cos\frac{2\pi}{5} + 2\cos \frac{4\pi}{5} = 0 $$

For the second question I did try a lot solving it, but I always end up doing something false or I get stuck in the middle.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I know but I didn't find how to write pi :) Thank you for correcting my faults

Comment: For $\pi$, write `\pi` (this extends to all letters of the Greek alphabet.)

Comment: Thank you I will remember that

Comment: Should the equation $-xy = -\frac{1}{4}$ read $xy = -\frac{1}{4}$?  If so, you could use your first result in solving the second problem.

Comment: No it's not the same thing I don't have a proof or some information to do that

Comment: I solved the second system of equations by using the result of solving the system of equations \begin{align*} x + y & = \frac{1}{2}\\ xy & = -\frac{1}{4} \end{align*}  The result checks.  The error in the statement of the first system of equations prevented you from using its result to solve the second system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system of equations in problem 1 should be 
\begin{align*}
x + y & = \frac{1}{2} \tag{1}\\
xy & = -\frac{1}{4} \tag{2}
\end{align*}
as the given system of equations has no real-valued solutions.

Solving equation 2 for $y$ yields
$$y = -\frac{1}{4x}$$
Substituting this expression for $y$ in equation 1 yields
$$x - \frac{1}{4x} = \frac{1}{2} \tag{3}$$
Multiplying both sides of equation 3 by $4x$, then solving the resulting quadratic equation yields
\begin{align*}
4x^2 - 1 & = 2x\\
4x^2 - 2x & = 1\\
x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x & = \frac{1}{4}\\
x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{16} & = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16}\\
\left(x - \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 & = \frac{5}{16}\\
x - \frac{1}{4} & = \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\\
x & = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}
\end{align*}
Solving equation 1 for $y$ yields 
$$y = \frac{1}{2} - x$$
Substituting $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}$ for $x$ yields 
$$y = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4} = \frac{1 \mp \sqrt{5}}{4}$$
Hence, the solutions of the first system of equations are $\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}, \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}, \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right)$.

The solution to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right) & = \frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right) & = -\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
can be obtained by letting $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)$ assume the role of $x$ and $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)$ assume the role of $y$ in the first system of equations, provided that we take into account the facts that
$$0  < \frac{\pi}{5} < \frac{\pi}{2} \implies \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) > 0$$
and that
$$\frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{3\pi}{5} < \pi \implies \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right) < 0$$
from which we conclude that 
\begin{align*}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) & = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\\
\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right) & = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}
\end{align*}
For the third question, note that the identity $\cos(\pi - \theta) = -\cos\theta$ implies that 
\begin{align*}
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) & = -\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)\\
\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right) & = -\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)
\end{align*}
which enables you to use the given equation
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$
to obtain the desired result.